# Using WM_USER, WM_APP or RegisterWindowMessage

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Currently, I have a Windows EXE application, with several loaded DLLs. DLLs need to communicate with my windows application through `PostMessage` and `SendMessage`.

The Windows EXE application + DLLs are all within a single process.

The message should be private among EXE and DLLs.

I was wondering, should I use

```
 - WM_USER based message
 - WM_APP based message
 - RegisterWindowMessage
```

and why?

What happen if there is an external process (another exe), trying to FindWindow of my Windows application, and send the message with same ID?

I wish not to respond, as I am only interested message from DLLs within my own process.

Answer (score 11):

WM_USER messages are typically used to implement control specific messages when developing a control. If you had developed an image editing control, and needed to allow users of the control to set the image, you might go:

```
#define IECM_SETIMAGE    (WM_USER+1) // image editor control message.
```

WM_APP messages are typically used to implement application level logic. If you want to send your application a specific message to perform an action...

```
#define IEAM_SHOWTOOLBAR   (WM_APP+1) // image editor app message
```

Having both WM_APP and WM_USER ranges seems a little redundant - however there are two use cases where having two ranges is necessary:

- it is possible to create a top level window from a control by simply making it overlapped or popup and giving it a menu and frame. It would then need to both respond as a control, and an application frame window.
- Applications can subclass controls, and then use the WM_APP channel for sending application defined messages to the controls without conflicting with the controls normal WM_USER range of messages.

RegisterWindowMessage is used to create messages when you need a unique message id that is system wide - typically because you want to broadcast the message to windows that are not under your own control, and hence have their own meanings for messages IDs in the WM_APP and WM_USER ranges.

Comment: OK. RegisterWindowMessage seems over do since I do not decide to perform any broadcast. But I still cannot get a conclusion, whether go for WM_APP or WM_USER based on the example you had given.

Comment: in your example, you would want to send a WM_APP message, as the modules are telling your application window to do something. If your application window was, for example, an EDIT control, you could not send a WM_USER message as that has meaning to the control.

Comment: Have you read this article before? http://www.flounder.com/messages.htm. Joseph M. Newcomer seems favoring RegisterWindowMessage over other.

Comment: My problem with RegisterWindowMessage is, they consume an exhaustible system resource with no method to clean up. If every application decided to register messages in place of using WM_APP when appropriate the system would start to fail to register new messages when run for long enough.

Comment: I presume that the RegisterWindowMessage only last until Windows restarts. I've just searched the Registry for one and didn't find it there.